# try mirroring webpage using pywebcopy

Tags: python-3.x

```
from pywebcopy.core import save_webpage

save_webpage(
        url='http://example-site.com/index.html',
        download_loc='d:/',
        copy_all=True
    )
```

I get this error when trying to run this program:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "D:/untitled7/mirror.py", line 6, in 
>           download_loc='d:/',
>       TypeError: save_webpage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mirrors_dir'

Comment: According to [pywebcopy github page](https://github.com/rajatomar788/pywebcopy) that is not how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

> For current version 6.0.0 as of github repo

You are using `copy_all=True` so I am guessing you want
to clone the whole website.

```py
from pywebcopy import save_website

kwargs = {'project_name': 'some-fancy-name'}

save_website(
    url='http://example-site.com/index.html',
    project_folder='path/to/downloads',
    **kwargs
)
```